# How to update deeply nested models that accept nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a problem mostly identical to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653519/couldnt-find-model-with-id-14-for-property-with-id-1#comment38270153_20653519).

I have three models call them Parent, Child, Grandchild.

```
Parent
has_many :children
has_many :grandchildren, through: children
```

When creating a parent, I assign children to it via collection check boxes. Now I need to update grandchildren association on the parent form. I set up

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
```

and I am able to update the attributes just like I need to.

The problem arises when I attempt to update a parent record. If I remove a child (through unclicking it's checkbox) I end up with the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
Couldn't find Child with ID=# for Parent with ID=#
```

even though this association is well defined in the database. On further investigation I found out the error was coming from

```
activerecord (4.1.1) lib/active_record/nested_attributes.rb:545:in `raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Ruby 1.9.3, Rails 4.1.1

In my controller I have

```
      params.require(:Parent).permit(:name, child_attributes: [:id, :grandchild_id],  :child_ids => [])
```

Comment: Does this error occurs when you go to the edit page of the children record, unclick its checkbox saying "related to parent X", submit the form and get redirected to the same page? If yes, this means that your routes forces AR to find a record via its id AND its (supposed) parent, which does not exist anymore.

Comment: Children are created independently and are associated by the Parent at a later time. So I don't have a checkbox on the child record saying "related to parent X".

Comment: I was not clear in my question. Does the error occur after you submit the form and get redirected to the edit page of the record updated?

Comment: No I can create the form fine. It only happens on update when I remove a child. My assumption was because it is trying to connect the nested attributes of the Grandchild with the Child of the current Parent and since that child was removed it can't find the child to associate the parent with and throws the error.

Comment: The given information doesn't allow to rebuild the case to analyze the problem. Please include the model source code for each model and the bottom part of the controller (i.e. the whitelisting part) in case we are talking about a Rails 4.x application.

Comment: @wintermeyer My code base is rather complex so what I provided is the simplest form I can provide. I have my parameters whitelisted properly. The important part of the models (the associations) is already provided. Like I wrote originally, the problem comes from accepts_nested_attributes_for.

Comment: @jkeuhlen If you did everything correct it would work. So the chance is pretty high that you did make a mistake (like we all have done so many times). The only solution to find that is to post a complete example.

Comment: @wintermeyer I added some example controller info. And I'm not claiming I'm perfect, but I am fairly certain my problem comes from using checkboxes with accepts_nested_attributes_for and not my controller or model set up (did plenty of debugging there first). And I believe it may just be a problem that derives from how rails handles nested attributes and check boxes along  with the update process. So I'm looking for a workaround or at least an explanation of how this process works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this arises from a security hole related to using existing ids in HABTM relationships. See:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rubyonrails-core/uWQVCKqQMVU

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyonrails-security/-fkT0yja_gw

The functionality will not be reintroduced