# How to remove has_many through association from Parent model by unchecking checkbox?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox, has-many-through

I'm really new to RoR and programming in general, and have read through a mind-numbing number of stackoverflow/railsforum/railscasts...etc. already and just can't seem to find a solution. My problem is nearly identical to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24684986/how-to-update-deeply-nested-models-that-accept-nested-attributes) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20653519/couldnt-find-model-with-id-14-for-property-with-id-1#comment38270153_20653519)--both of which have unfortunately not been answered.

I have 3 models: Project, Task, and Assignments. I have a collection of checkboxes of existing Tasks (using simple_form and cocoon) that the user can select from, to add to a Project. Adding Tasks through checking their boxes works, but I cannot uncheck boxes and remove the association (Assignment). When I try to save my changes, I'm met with this error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ProjectsController#update error: 
Couldn't find Task with ID=28 for Project with ID=39.
    def raise_nested_attributes_record_not_found!(association_name, record_id)
```

My guess is that AR is looking for a Task that has already been disassociated from the Project, but that's just a hunch. If that's the case, I'd still have no clue where and how to fix this problem.

Project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :assignments, dependent: :delete_all
has_many :tasks, :through => :assignments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :tasks, reject_if: :all_blank
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments, :allow_destroy => true
```

Task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :assignments
has_many :projects, :through => :assignments
accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignments
```

Assignment.rb

```
class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
belongs_to :task
accepts_nested_attributes_for :project, :reject_if => :all_blank
```

Project controller#update

```
def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    params[:project][:task_ids] ||= []
    if @project.update_attributes(project_params)
        flash[:success] = "Your project has been updated!"
        redirect_to @project
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

private
    def project_params
        params.require(:project).permit(:job_code, :task_ids => [], 
                                        tasks_attributes: 
                                        [:id, :item, :description, :requirement, :complexity, 
                                         :est_time, :actual_time, :_destroy],
                                        assignments_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :task_id])
    end
```

I would greatly appreciate any help/insight/hand-holding to solve this problem! Way too much time has been spent trying to figure it out on my own, considering my limited knowledge of rails.

Thanks!

**EDIT: form code included** 
Project edit.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Edit project") %>
<h1>Update your project status</h1>

<div class="row">
    <%= minimal_form_for @project, html: { class: "form-inline"} do |f| %>
        <% if @project.errors.any? %>
            <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <% end %>
        <h4>Choose an existing task</h4>
        <%= f.association :tasks, :collection => Task.all.to_a, :label_method => :item,
                                      :as => :check_boxes,
                                      :wrapper => :vertical_radio_and_checkboxes,
                                      :checked => params[:task_id] %>
        <%= render 'form', f: f %>
        <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Project _form.html.erb

```
<h3>Tasks</h3>
<div id="tasks">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :tasks do |task| %>
        <%= render "projects/task_fields", :f => task %>
    <% end %>
    <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association "Add task", f, :tasks, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
</div>
```

Project _task_fields.html.erb

```
<div class="nested-fields">
    <%= f.input :item %>
    <%= f.input :description %>
    <%= f.input :complexity, collection: Task.complexities.keys, :selected => '' %>
    <%= f.input :est_time %>
    <%= f.input :actual_time %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "Remove task", f, class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add form code and explain this line 'params[:project][:task_ids] ||= []'

Comment: Updated my question with the form code. The line 'params[:project][:task_ids] ||= []' was used in place of a hidden_field_tag in my form. In case no checkboxes are checked, the task_id array will be passed in as empty, since HTML checkboxes don't submit a value if they're empty.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `check_box` named `:_destroy` to signal you want it deleted.

Check the guide on this matter: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#nested-forms